# Execute C# code from aspx at ASP.NET MVC 4

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

I have a ASP.NET MVC4 project.

I have different types of users, like child, teenager and adults, all of which belong to the User Role "User". Every one of these should see a different menu when they log in.

So I thought that it would be a good idea to check if a logged in user is a child for example to display child's menu at the Site.Master (which is written in aspx).

I have however difficulties to do that. My code below gets a 
`Parser Error Message: The server block is not well formed.` message at the second line 
(`<%@ using SchoolProgressProject.Controllers %>`  ).
My code is shown below.

```
<%@ Import Namespace="SchoolProgressProject" %>  
                <%@ using SchoolProgressProject.Controllers; %>  
                <%@ using SchoolProgressProject.Models; %>  
                <% WebIntegrationRestService service= new WebIntegrationRestService();//This is to contact the Database%>
             <% UserType type = null;%>
            <%if (User.Identity.IsAuthenticated)%>
            <%{%>
                  <% UserType type = service.GetUserByUsername(User.Identity.Name).UserType;%>
            <%}%>
```

Do you know how I can *fix that*? In addition do you know an *easier, or more clear* way to do this?

Comment: Don't the statements need to be terminated with ;

Comment: @MikeBeeler, yes, this it true. I am correcting that now at my question. however I have them with ; in my code, and I get the same message.

Comment: `<%@` looks like a mix of regular aspx syntax and Razor. Try replacing these tags with `<%`, except for the first one.

Comment: @Zruty I did that but they do not work either

Comment: That said, the entire approach looks bad to me. You can be more concise by moving your authorization code to the controller, and you can write cleaner HTML with Razor engine

Comment: Did you try `<%@ Import Namespace="SchoolProgressProject.Controllers" %>` etc.?

Comment: @Zruty. OK, I also agree with that! but how? The problem is that I cannot call my C# code! (btw I am not using Razor, but aspx)

Comment: You need to do what @Zruty says. You also need to not do this at all, because it is plain wrong. This logic should go in your controller and then relevant information for view logic should be put in a view model.

Comment: An easier way would be to use a _Layout.cshtml as your masterpage and get rid of the webforms all together, I am assuming the Site.master is legacy code that has lots of code already and would be time consuming to port that functionality to MVC?

Comment: @BrianOgden site.master is just a masterpage for the aspx view engine - does much the same as _layout.cshtml. OP says he's not using Razor so porting isn't really the answer

Comment: @Zruty Thanks a lot! Yes, indeed that saved me! You are awesome Zruty. Btw guys, thanks a lot  for your advices. I know that my code is not clear at all, and that's also the reason I asked that at my question. Thank you all a lot. I will see your responses with more detail, and I will remove my code from master site.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A couple of points.

You can't use `using` in a view page, like you do in c# code file. They work in different ways. The import page directive does the equivalent.

Multiple lines of code don't need `<%` on each line like you've done. a A code block starts with aa `<%`, has multiple lines of code each terminated with a `;` & finally a `%>`

Lastly & most importantly DO NOT DO THIS IN THE VIEW. Your view should not have business logic in it. Get the user role in the controller, then pass the result to the view, or return a different view based on the value.

Comment: Actually you could @{} block...

Comment: If you were using Razor, yes. OP says he's using aspx.

Comment: Thanks a lot Simon! I didn't know that! you were very helpful! I +1 your answer

Answer (score 0):

If this is an mvc 4 project consider using razor syntax, if the controller needs to reference a namespace:

- add a reference to the project
- change the import to a using statement

Lastly for reference, look at the output of the intranet mvc project template to see what the layout for controller / view code should be

Comment: Thanks a lot Mike. However, I think I cannot choose your answer as best answer, because I am asking something different, and also with a specific code. Changing the import to a using, was the first thing I thought, but unfortunately, this could not solve the problem...

Comment: A less cluttered syntax would be razor, second most of the code can be moved to the controller and if you define a property in your model the controller can update the model before rendering the view. The conditional code in your view to set the link ( in the duplicate question you asked ) can be set or not depending on value

Answer (score -1):

I might help if you explained why you are trying to use a web forms master page in an MVC 4 project?  Even if it's a legacy product there's no real reason why it can't be ported.

Also, just because you're using MVC doesn't mean you have to use Razor, you can still use .ASPX in your pages.

You'd be better making the menu a partial view with a controller running the required logic to determine the type of user and therefore the menu system.

You then reference the partial view in the _layout page.

To do what your are doing is a major fudge! ;-)

Comment: site.master is perfectly acceptable when using aspx view engine & does not imply web forms